# Django- Postgres: raise TypeError("Model instances without primary key value are unhashable")

Tags: django, postgresql, database-migration

Now I'm working on Django project with postgresql.
When I did `python3 manage.py migrate`, I got following error.

```
raise TypeError("Model instances without primary key value are unhashable")
```

I have no idea, where I got this error and how to solve this.

Comment: post your model files

Comment: I have a lot of model files. it's not easy to post my models here since I don't know the exact models that cause problems. Can you provide me the general cause why this error happens?

Comment: have you done makemigrations before running migrate?

Comment: yes, I have done makemigration

Comment: I think before I got this error, I got "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table" error.

Comment: I did python3 manage.py migrate --fake. Then I got this error.

Comment: `manage.py migrate --traceback` ?

Comment: @Anton.Y you could run `manage.py migrate --traceback` as instructed by user Kos to narrow down on where the error could be originating, so you can show us the model that has the problem.